# Rewriting authentication controller using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparative-review, authentication, promise

I am in the process of refactoring some complex code that uses callbacks to instead use promises. I am trying to figure out if my proposed approaches make sense.

```
/*
  Current implementation.
  Hard to test because of the intermingling of various controller functionality,
  such as preparing responses.
  Gets a little deep on the nesting.
 */

controller.authenticate = function(req, res) {

  var customerCode = req.body.customerCode;
  var accountType = req.body.accountType;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  if (!(customerCode && accountType && username && password)) return helper.handleInvalidRequest(res);

  Account.findByAccountTypeAndUsername(accountType, username, function(err, account) {

    if (err) return helper.handleError(res, err);
    if (!account) return helper.handleNotFound(res);

    account.authenticatePassword(password, function(err, authenticated) {

      if (err) return helper.handleError(res, err);

      if (account.status == 'Locked') {
        var pass = new VisitorPass({accountID: account._id});
        return pass.save(function(err) {
          if (err) return helper.handleError(res, err);
          messaging.sendAccountLockedMessage(customerCode, account, pass, null);
          return helper.handleLockedAccount(res, pass);
        });
      }

      if (!authenticated) return helper.handleNotAuthenticated(res);

      if (account.tfaEnabled && !account.deviceIsTrusted(req.trustedDeviceToken)) {
        if (account.tfaMethod == 'sms') {
          var hotp = account.getNextHotp();
          return account.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return helper.handleError(res, err);
            messaging.sendOneTimePasswordAuthenticationMessage(account.tfaPhone, hotp, null);
            return helper.handleTfaRequired(res, account, auth.createPartiallyAuthenticatedJWT(account._id));
          });
        }
        else {
          return helper.handleTfaRequired(res, account, auth.createPartiallyAuthenticatedJWT(account._id));
        }
      }
      else {
        res.status(201).send({token: auth.createFullyAuthenticatedJWT(account._id)});
      }

    });

  });

};
```

First approach at refactoring:

```
/*
  Moves work to a new AccountService.authenticate method, which would return
  a promise.
 */

controller.authenticate = function(req, res) {

  var customerCode = req.body.customerCode;
  var accountType = req.body.accountType;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  AccountService.authenticate(customerCode, accountType, username, password)
    .then(function(token) {
      res.status(201).send({token: token});
    })
    .catch(InvalidRequestError, function() {
      helper.handleInvalidRequest(res);
    })
    .catch(NotFoundError, function() {
      helper.handleNotFound(res);
    })
    .catch(AccountLockedError, function(err) {
      return helper.handleLockedAccount(res, err.pass);
    })
    .catch(NotAuthenticatedError, function() {
      helper.handleNotAuthenticated(res);
    })
    .catch(TwoFactorAuthRequiredError, function(err) {
      helper.handleTfaRequired(res, err.account, err.token);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      helper.handleError(res, err);
    });

};
```

Second approach to refactoring:

```
/*
 In-between alternative. Still handles request validation itself.
 Modifies two methods (Account.findByAccountTypeAndUsername and account.authenticate)
 to return promises.
 */

controller.authenticate = function(req, res) {

  var customerCode = req.body.customerCode;
  var accountType = req.body.accountType;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  if (!(customerCode && accountType && username && password)) return helper.handleInvalidRequest(res);

  Account.findByAccountTypeAndUsername(accountType, username)
    .then(function(account) {
      return account.authenticate(password)
        .then(function(token) {
          res.status(201).send({token: token});
        })
        .catch(AccountLockedError, function(err) {
          return helper.handleLockedAccount(res, err.pass);
        })
        .catch(NotAuthenticatedError, function() {
          helper.handleNotAuthenticated(res);
        })
        .catch(TwoFactorAuthRequiredError, function(err) {
          helper.handleTfaRequired(res, err.account, err.token);
        });
    })
    .catch(NotFoundError, function() {
      helper.handleNotFound(res);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      helper.handleError(res, err);
    });

};
```

I have a few specific questions:

1. Are these good scenarios for using promises over callbacks?
2. Is the use of custom error types like `AccountLockedError` acceptable in this kind of scenario?
3. In the third example, because the first promise was fulfilled with the "account" object, I had to nest the next call and promise chain. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Be careful about saying "refactoring" when you really just mean "rewriting".